# Trigger updating all rows of a table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have the date type column valid_upto in the users table which is a foreign key referring to the valid_upto column in the subscription table. I need users.valid_upto to update when a change is made to subscription.valid_upto where the corresponding user ID values match. Currently the trigger updates all rows in the users table when a single row is changed in the subscription table. It basically ignores the WHERE clause.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `valid_date` ;
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `valid_date` AFTER UPDATE ON `users`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
UPDATE valid_upto SET users.valid_upto = subscription.valid_upto WHERE users.id = subscription.user_id;
END ;
```

Comment: Your `update` should be generating a syntax error.  Moreover, copying values from one table to a bunch of rows in another table is suspicious and seems like a very poor use of a trigger.  Just do the `JOIN` when querying the data.

Comment: The intention is to have it update a single row only, based on the unique user ID.

Comment: That update statement seems incorrect. It is missing a inner join to the subscription table. Unless mysql syntax allows this.

Comment: I gave it a go but it did not change anything at all in the users table.                                                                                                            BEGIN
    UPDATE users
    INNER JOIN users.id ON subscription.user_id
    SET users.valid_upto = NEW.subscription.valid_upto
   WHERE subscription.valid_upto IS NOT NULL;
   END;